# normal pass from volumetric shader [EEVEE]

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to export a kind of Normal Pass from a group of cubes with a volumetric shader inside.
Is it possible to do? I'vesearched a bit and I've found some tips for recreating normals into shaders, but when I try to transport it into volumetric all goes wrong.

[The file if you need it:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16om_1XtKbNZpyOIDnkpyVSYHCDo7G9Hp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Volumetric (only) mats do not not have normals, because normals are a property of *surfaces*.  The best that you're going to get from that is getting the normals of the cubes defining the volume.  You are not going to get the apparent surface of some cool procedural volumetric, because that surface is *only* apparent, not actual.

Comment: Oh, ok, but is there a way to simulate that? I mean a way to make rgb colors to appear in three different direction? (Like normal pass do?)